# Issues while copy/pasting values from Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to read a source Excel file and copying some of the values and assigning the same to different cells in the target sheet. But after execution of the macro. the value pasted are not as expected.

Code:

```
Sub Import()
Dim SourceFile As Workbook
Dim SourceTab As Worksheet
Dim TargetTab As Worksheet

SourceFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files , *.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv")

If SourceFileName = False Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set TargetTab = Sheets("Output")
'TargetRow = TargetTab.Cells(TargetTab.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
TargetRow = 2
Set SourceFile = Workbooks.Open(SourceFileName)

SourceFile.Activate
Set SourceTab = Sheets("Input")
SourceTab.Activate

For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If SourceTab.Cells(i, 2) = "VS" Then
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 3).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 31).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 5).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 11).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 6).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 19).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 7).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 27).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 5).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 4).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 11).Value = SourceTab.Cells(4, 5).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 13).Value = SourceTab.Cells(2, 25).Value
        TargetTab.Cells(i, 16).Value = SourceTab.Cells(i, 8).Value

        SourceTab.Cells(i, 3).Resize(1, 50).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Activate
        TargetTab.Activate
        Cells(TargetRow, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        SourceFile.Activate

        TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
        'TargetNewRows = TargetNewRows + 1
    End If

Next
SourceFile.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone would you please help me on this fiasco!!!

Comment: **Are you say that the paste works without error, but the values pasted are incorrect??**

Comment: I have modified the code and now its working fine... But when I run the macro in Excel 2007 its getting completed within 30 seconds, whereas in Office 365 proplus its running for more than half an hour and not getting completed at all..  here is the modified code.. can you please check and advise.

Answer (score 1):

As Gary's comment indicates, your problem is not very clear, however, I'll give it a shot.

Note that in:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

the `Cells(...` expression is evaluated every iteration of the loop. If the selection changes during the loop, then it can give a different result every iteration. I suggest you do something like:

```
j = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To j
```